# How could I use one route with git for multiple developers in Laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I have only one routes **app/routes.php**, I am using **git /git-hub** for sharing my projects with some developers. Cause they can work together. But problem is that : every one using same **routes.php** file for routing and when they **push/pull** in git this **routes.php** file conflicts all the time.

Is there any way to set routes for different developer in same project ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a silly way but fruitful::

1. create routes_demo.php :: here demo developer can work
2. Include routes_demo.php in your main routes.php

include more as your need. Enjoy sharing codes /projects.

THanks

Answer (score 2):

This is what Github is all about - collaboration between multiple developers.

There are many ways to handle this - but in general each developer can fork his own branch - make changes - then merge them back in.

You will expect conflicts on the file - but the conflicts should not be the same route - it should be different routes in the same file - so you can merge the conflict into the one route file

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there any example/resources that I can go through on them ? Please

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8508861/two-people-working-on-a-file-at-the-same-time-in-git

Comment: Or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028845/how-two-people-concurrently-editing-the-same-file-is-handled

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use controllers to define routing logic, so your routes.php file does not get complicated. You will avoid a lot of conflicts this way. You can read more [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#basic-controllers). Pasting an excerpt:

> Instead of defining all of your route-level logic in a single routes.php file, you may wish to organize this behavior using Controller classes. Controllers can group related route logic into a class, as well as take advantage of more advanced framework features such as automatic dependency injection.

Comment: But we are using routes for Controller. When we push or pull it conflicts